# Laravel: __construct() must be an instance of Dompdf\Dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

It tried this code but it's not working. What is the problem?  How can I fix that?

```
     public function PDF(Invoice $invoice)
        {
            $items = unserialize($invoice->items);
            $fileName =$invoice->invoice_code;
            $pdf = new PDF($invoice);
            $pdf->loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoice', 'items'));
            return $pdf->stream($fileName . '.pdf');
        }
```

> Argument 1 passed to Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct() must be an 
>       instance of Dompdf\Dompdf, instance of App\Invoice given, called in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping-cart\app\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController.php

Comment: Try replacing `new PDF($invoice)` with just `new PDF()`

Comment: or use the static method since it's a facade `$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoice', 'items'));` no need to instantiate it beforehand

Comment: First thanks for your answer, I tried new PDF(); but it give me error like "Too few arguments to function Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(), 0 passed"

Comment: I used the method static `$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoice', 'items'));` it return the error "Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::loadView() should not be called statically"

Comment: use the facade class ` Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class` and if you want to use it on the main namespace, declare it in `config.php` in aliases `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,`

Comment: I added it's provider and alias to config\app.php as `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class` and alias as `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class` and use the name space in my controller as `use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;` and publish theme but the error still there! :(

Comment: dont add `use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;` use the alias `$pdf = \PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf'..` added an answer to make it clearer

Comment: I remove the use statement from my controller and used the alias like `$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoice', 'items'));` but it give me error "Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::loadView() should not be called statically"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facade either directly with:

```php
use use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
...
public function PDF(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $items = unserialize($invoice->items);
    $fileName =$invoice->invoice_code;
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoice', 'items'));
    return $pdf->stream($fileName . '.pdf');
}
```

of after adding it to `config.php` in aliases:

config.php

```php
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
],
```

Controller

```
//no use needed
...
public function PDF(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $items = unserialize($invoice->items);
    $fileName =$invoice->invoice_code;
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoice', 'items'));
    return $pdf->stream($fileName . '.pdf');
}
```

Comment: i try that but the page still refreshing :)

Comment: @Mostafa generating a pdf take time, it also depends on the size of the document. either way, you're not getting the initialisation error anymore which was the issue here.